# I need to perform naive bayes text classification. Getting error while running the naiveBayes() method

Tags: r, text-classification, naivebayes

I am getting an error while using naiveBayes() method in R. I am passing the the as.matrix(train_matrix)as first parameter and  as.factor(train_data$subcategory) to the naiveBayes function.

I am getting below error :

model <- naiveBayes(as.matrix(trainmatrix),as.factor(traindata$subCategory));
Error in tapply(var, y, mean, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  arguments must have same length

Can anyone help me on this?

```
model <- naiveBayes(as.matrix(trainmatrix),as.factor(traindata$subCategory));
```

Where trainMatrix is term document matrix, traindata - is the data on which in need the model to get trained on and subCategory is the class (different levels).

Am i doing it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that your matrix(train matrix) is not the same length as the data frame(train data) which is obviously expected.
use the syntax 
model<-naiveBayes(traindata$subCategory~.,data=traindata)

Comment: @ i have got the prediction result in the form of a factor but now i am not able to calculate the confustion matrix!! Can anyone share the way to do it??

Answer (score 0):

Done with creating model and confusion matrix. Below are the code snippet:

```
model <- naiveBayes(as.matrix(trainmatrix),as.factor(traindata$subCategory));

confusionMatrix(results, traindata$subCategory)
```

Where results is the prediction outcome.
Note : The length of results and traindatat$subcategory has to be same,(which i was missing).